# Limit the scope of elements in a html form

Tags: html

I have a HTML page with multiple forms and all these forms have the elements with same id. And I am using ajax calls to submit these forms. But the forms(except for the first one) do have the entries as the IDs are same and I want to know if there is a way to limit the scope of these elements to the form.

I understand that I can give different IDs and I am actually doing that. I just thought its good to know if there is a way to limit the scope.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "scope"? You can't have two elements with the same ID.

Comment: Ids _have_ to be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: @CBroe I know that the ids have to be unique. I am just trying to know if there is a way to trick the HTML renderer into thinking there is only element with the same ID per page, where there is only one per <div>. I actually do not know how the HTML documents are parsed and rendered.

Answer (score 0):

include the parent element. Example:

```
$('section.header>form.search')
```

Otherwise just add another differentiating class. Example:

```
<div class="row header">
```